# Using php mhash functions to create a key from a string

Tags: php

I am planning on using the php function `mcrypt` to encrypt and decrypt some data stored in an SQL database.

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
```

I am stuck at what to use for `$key`.  The php manual recommends using, *"mhash functions to create a key from a string"*.  So what's the best way to do that using mhash and get a 256 bit key out of it? Do I do something like this?

```
mhash(MHASH_SHA256, $mystring);
```

How many characters do I need for `$mystring`?

Comment: does using MHASH_SHA256 mean that I will get 256 bits back regardless of the length of $mystring?

Comment: What do you need to encrypt? Why do you need to encrypt it? The idea is that you can only decrypt data if you have the key used for encryption. If you just store your key along with your application, it hardly secures anything.

Comment: I need to encrypt sensitive data because it is sensitive. :) My application needs access to the key, so I'm not sure where else I would keep it.  I figure it's safe as long as no one hacks into my server, and if they hack into it I'm pretty much screwed at that point anyway.

Comment: That's an odd argument. If they hack into your server, you say you're screwed anyway. But if they don't hack in, they can't access the data anyway, so your encryption is useless. What kind of sensitive date? You might want to ask yourself if you need to save this data at all. If it's user data, consider encrypting it using the user's key, so the keys are never stored on your server.

Comment: Someone logs into the site, no need to hack anything.  They enter the data, it's encrypted and stored in the database.  Then later they or someone else will view the data (which is then decrypted).  A lot of places online store private info like birth dates, etc. without requiring the user to enter a key, and they must be storing the key somewhere, so I'm not sure I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many characters you pass for `$mystring`, `mhash` will return 32 characters every time.

A simple test on the command line will illustrate

```
php > var_dump(mhash(MHASH_SHA256, 'blah'));
string(32) "?}?C?qnϥ?0/kB???R??e?`0?R"
php > var_dump(mhash(MHASH_SHA256, 'blahadfadf'));
string(32) "t?+jm~8??f?vD???'?R????a:??巯"
php > var_dump(mhash(MHASH_SHA256, 'blasdfafadf'));
string(32) "<?Z,?????,m???\5k??i???B???"
php > var_dump(mhash(MHASH_SHA256, 'blasasdfasdfasdfasf'));
string(32) "?]?,5Þظ?&x??T{?8?]?5??  Y?"
php > var_dump(mhash(MHASH_SHA256, 'blasasdfasdfasdfasfadfjads;fkjas;ldkfjas;dkjfa;sdjkf'));
string(32) "j?̳ebb??Z'??????9??^s???F"
```

Comment: Honestly I'm unsure why my code had 14 char requirement! I just tried by putting in `mhash(MHASH_SHA256, 'blah')` for the nonce and it worked just fine. Probably a relic from some old code. Sorry for that!